# New Wooden decking. To stain or not to stain

Tags: wood, decking, stain, pressure-treated

I had new wooden decking installed on my balcony.
The guy that did the job says it doesn't need stain because the wood is already treated: http://www.diy.com/departments/premium-brown-softwood-deck-board-t28mm-w144mm-l3600mm/945944_BQ.prd

He said to sand and stain it in two years time, but I was wondering if I stain it now maybe it will last more than two years?
I live in London so, as you probably know, it rains A LOT. Wood is a very poor choice, but I can't change it because of the rules in my apartment lease.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what preservative-treated means. [Edit: lower in the page it specifically reads "pressure-treated".] Around here, pressure-treated lumber is soaking wet and not suitable for stain/sealer until it's dried at least an entire season.

If it's truly kiln-dried, you're free to apply a stain/sealer at any time. To preserve color and prevent surface degradation, sooner is better.

Comment: +1 for the edit, but I still think it's just normal pressure treated, which might be kiln dried before pressure treating. Here's an interesting [video about pressure treating](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ed582Y2_pjk) (if you care).

Comment: That's what I meant. Typical PT lumber is kiln-dried before treatment but not after. Or at least not very well after.

Answer (score 0):

He's probably right, but you should have someone check it in about 6 months... any painter worth his salt will tell you if it's too soon.

This appears to be similar to [How long should I wait before painting or staining pressure-treated wood?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/28548/how-long-should-i-wait-before-painting-or-staining-pressure-treated-wood)